# При вычислении площади треугольника по формуле Герона получается минус ноль. Java

Tags: java

Выполняю задачку на нахождение площади различных фигур.
Задал интерфейс Shape.java:

```
package info.sjd;

public interface Shape {

    float getArea();
}
```

Затем класс AbastractShape.java:

```
package info.sjd;

public abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {

    public abstract float getArea();

}
```

В Triangle.java задаю площадь через формулу Герона:

```
package info.sjd.triangle;

import info.sjd.AbstractShape;

public class Triangle extends AbstractShape {

    private float aSide, bSide, cSide;
    private float halfPerimeter = (float) ((aSide + bSide + cSide) * 0.5);

    public float getaSide() {
        return aSide;
    }

    public void setaSide(float aSide) {
        this.aSide = aSide;
    }

    public float getbSide() {
        return bSide;
    }

    public void setbSide(float bSide) {
        this.bSide = bSide;
    }

    public float getcSide() {
        return cSide;
    }

    public void setcSide(float cSide) {
        this.cSide = cSide;
    }

    public float getHalfPerimeter() {
        return halfPerimeter;
    }

    public void setHalfPerimeter(float halfPerimeter) {
        this.halfPerimeter = halfPerimeter;
    }

        @Override
    public float getArea() {
    return (float) Math.sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - aSide) * (halfPerimeter - bSide) * (halfPerimeter - cSide));
    }

}
```

В AppRunner.java вывожу площади фигур, чтобы увидеть, что же получилось:

```
package info.sjd;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import info.sjd.circle.Circle;
import info.sjd.rectangle.Rectangle;
import info.sjd.square.Square;
import info.sjd.triangle.Triangle;
import info.sjd.triangle2.Triangle2;

public class AppRunner {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppRunner.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Finding Triangle Area through three sides

    Triangle triangle11 = new Triangle();
    triangle11.setaSide(3);
    triangle11.setbSide(4);
    triangle11.setcSide(5);
    logger.info("Triangle with a side=" + triangle11.getaSide() + ", b side=" + triangle11.getbSide() + " and c side=" + triangle11.getcSide() + " has area " + triangle11.getArea());

    Triangle triangle12 = new Triangle();
    triangle12.setaSide(13);
    triangle12.setbSide(14);
    triangle12.setcSide(15);
    logger.info("Triangle with a side=" + triangle12.getaSide() + ", b side=" + triangle12.getbSide() + " and c side=" + triangle12.getcSide() + " has area " + triangle12.getArea());

    Triangle triangle13 = new Triangle();
    triangle13.setaSide(10);
    triangle13.setbSide(11);
    triangle13.setcSide(12);
    logger.info("Triangle with a side=" + triangle13.getaSide() + ", b side=" + triangle13.getbSide() + " and c side=" + triangle13.getcSide() + " has area " + triangle13.getArea());

    // Finding Triangle Area through its base and height

    Triangle2 triangle21 = new Triangle2();
    triangle21.setBase(10);
    triangle21.setHeight(5);
    logger.info("Triangle with base=" + triangle21.getBase() + "and height=" + triangle21.getHeight() + " has area=" + triangle21.getArea());

    Triangle2 triangle22 = new Triangle2();
    triangle22.setBase(13);
    triangle22.setHeight(7);
    logger.info("Triangle with base=" + triangle22.getBase() + "and height=" + triangle22.getHeight() + " has area=" + triangle22.getArea());
    }

}
```

Здесь класс Triangle2 - это проверочный класс, для нахождения площади треугольника через его высоту и основание:

```
package info.sjd.triangle2;

import info.sjd.AbstractShape;

public class Triangle2 extends AbstractShape {

    private int base, height;

    public int getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(int base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public float getArea() {

        return (float) ((float) base * height * 0.5);
    }

}
```

Вот что выдает AppRunner:

```
вер. 26, 2018 10:05:02 AM info.sjd.AppRunner main
INFO: Triangle with a side=3.0, b side=4.0 and c side=5.0 has area -0.0
вер. 26, 2018 10:05:02 AM info.sjd.AppRunner main
INFO: Triangle with a side=13.0, b side=14.0 and c side=15.0 has area -0.0
вер. 26, 2018 10:05:02 AM info.sjd.AppRunner main
INFO: Triangle with a side=10.0, b side=11.0 and c side=12.0 has area -0.0
вер. 26, 2018 10:05:02 AM info.sjd.AppRunner main
INFO: Triangle with base=10and height=5 has area=25.0
вер. 26, 2018 10:05:02 AM info.sjd.AppRunner main
INFO: Triangle with base=13and height=7 has area=45.5
```

Убирал деление, квадратный корень из формулы - все равно площадь получается -0.0.

Что может быть за ошибка? Может что-то с типами?

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь вычислить периметр ещё на момент создания объекта. А значение перенных-сторон на тот момент ноль.

Как пофиксить?

строку

```
private float halfPerimeter = (float) ((aSide + bSide + cSide) * 0.5);
```

удалить, а метод getHalfPerimeter написать так:

```
public float getHalfPerimeter() {
    return (aSide + bSide + cSide) * 0.5;
}
```

метод `setHalfPerimeter` как то бессмыслен.